# 3D line vector and plane Intersection

Tags: python, vector, sympy, intersection, plane

I have a *3D line vector* given in the form of **ai + bj + ck**. I am calculating a *plane* using 3 points as given below.

```
from sympy import Point3D, Plane
def def_surface (a1,a2,a3):
    Flat1 = Plane(Point3D(a1), Point3D(a2), Point3D(a3)) 
    S = Flat1.equation()
    return S
```

I want to find the point `P(x,y,z)` where the line meets the plane.

P.S.
Do I have to create a parametric equation after finding a point on a line?
Or is there an easy way to get to the intersection point directly?

Assuming I have a point on a line S = (d,e,f), is there an easy way to find the intersection point?

Comment: the origin is one point of the line?

Comment: That is one of my concerns. Do I have to create a parametric equation after finding a point on a line?
Or is there an easy way to get to the intersection point directly?

Comment: A line could be defined by a point and a vector, or two points. so you need some more information than just a vector for that

Comment: Yes, I can find a point on the line. 
Assuming I have a point how to get the intersection point?

Comment: nono, you need another point in the line, you only have a vector...

Comment: If you have a line equation, and one for the plane as the code suggests, you can probably solve the two equations to find (x, y, z)?

Comment: I have the directional vector and a point on the line.

Comment: @typedecker it's more simple than that, if you work with sympy object for a plane and a line you could find the insersection with the object methods

Comment: @UlisesBussi Thanks for the info <3 I actually did not know that, I do not use sympy often, what led me here was the python tag and I was trying to answer it using my math knowledge(atleast the amount I have).

Comment: @typedecker it's okey I just wanted to clarify that because the OP proposed sympy. but I think the best way to solve this without the library is as you say just mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a slight adjustment to @Ulises Bussi's answer.
Line = Line3D(p0,v0) is not giving the output we need. when p0 is a point and v0 is a vector, the Correct line equation will be given as,

`line = Line3D(p0,direction_ratio=v0)`

Hence the correct way of doing this would be:

```
#plane Points
a1 = Point3D (-5,15,-5)
a2 = Point3D (5,15,-5)
a3 = Point3D (5,15,5)
#line Points
p0 = Point3D (0,3,1) #point in line
v0 = [0, 1 ,1] #line direction as vector

#create plane and line
plane = Plane(a1,a2,a3)

line = Line3D(p0,direction_ratio=v0)


print(f"plane equation: {plane.equation()}")
print(f"line equation: {line.equation()}")

#find intersection:

intr = plane.intersection(line)

intersection =np.array(intr[0],dtype=float)
print(f"intersection: {intersection}")
```

Answer (score 2):

When using sympy its important to conservate the whole object to find the intersection and not just the equation.

Suposing you have the direction and one point in the line you could do this:

```
from sympy import Plane, Line3D #Point3D it's not needed here

#plane Points
a1 = [1,0,0]
a2 = [0,1,0]
a3 = [0,0,1]
#line Points
p0 = [0,0,0] #point in line
v0 = [1,1,1] #line direction as vector

#create plane and line
plane = Plane(a1,a2,a3)
line = Line3D(p0,direction_ratio=v0)

print(f"plane equation: {plane.equation()}")
print(f"line equation: {line.equation()}")

#find intersection:

intr = plane.intersection(line)

print(f"intersection: {intr}")
```

### *Outputs*

```
plane equation: x + y + z - 1
line equation: (-x + y, -x + z)
intersection: [Point3D(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I have 2 clarifications. 
1. Why intr always show up with "Point3D" ? can I get it just as point output? 
2. Any reason that these outputs return as fractions? ( how to get it in decimal points) 
Thank you

Comment: because the intersection return a list of objects points in the library. you could get it with numpy, not sure how to convert it to a list: `import numpy as np; intersection_array =np.array(intr[0],dtype=float)`

Comment: no worries, remember to check libraries documentation and often object methods (I didn't know this could be done 1 hour before this post)

Comment: Hey. This works perfectly as long as P0 is (0,0,0) I tested with the same line and different starting points. Results seem to be giving random outputs. 
ex: Plane in X-Z at y = 15, with vector (0,1,1) - when P(0) is =0,0,0 answers are correct but when you change it to even (0,1,0) output is wrong.

Comment: As I understood, line = Line3D(p0,v0) is not giving the output we need. when p0 is a point and v0 is a vector. line = Line3D(p0,v0) to work both p0 and v0 have to be points.

Comment: cannot understand the new problem, make an edit in the post with all infomation pls